# Running a query to see the comparison of bounce count to # of block bounces and my query is returning 0

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql, subquery, bounce-management

Here's my code. I tested the subquery and it returns records. But when I join it it returns nothing for some reason.

```
SELECT sub.SubscriberKey
,sub.BounceCount
,sub.Status
,bb.BlockBounceCount
,(sub.BounceCount - bb.BlockBounceCount) AS NonBlockBounceCount

FROM 
(SELECT b.SubscriberKey
,CONVERT(NVARCHAR,COUNT(*)) AS BlockBounceCount
FROM _Bounce b 
WHERE b.BounceCategory = 'Block bounce' 
GROUP BY b.SubscriberKey) bb

JOIN _Subscribers sub ON sub.SubscriberKey = bb.SubscriberKey
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be happening, because you are running this query in your child BU. Your subscribers reside in your parent BU. You need to append `ENT.` prefix in your query for `_Subscribers` data view.

```
SELECT sub.SubscriberKey
,sub.BounceCount
,sub.Status
,bb.BlockBounceCount
,(sub.BounceCount - bb.BlockBounceCount) AS NonBlockBounceCount

FROM 
(SELECT b.SubscriberKey
,CONVERT(NVARCHAR,COUNT(*)) AS BlockBounceCount
FROM _Bounce b 
WHERE b.BounceCategory = 'Block bounce' 
GROUP BY b.SubscriberKey) bb

JOIN ENT._Subscribers sub ON sub.SubscriberKey = bb.SubscriberKey
```

Comment: Thank you! That was it!